# Getting Cannot read property 'saveUpload' of undefined while passing props via function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var Admin = React.createClass({
  saveUpload: function(id) {
    alert(id);
  },

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      uploads: []
    };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/admin/uploads',
      success: function(data) {
        self.setState({
          uploads: data
        })
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var obj = this.state.uploads.map(function(product) {
      return ( 
        <Uploads product = {product}
        saveHandle = {this.saveUpload}
        />
      )
    });

    return ( 
     < div >
      <div className = "container" >
      <br / >
      <h1 className = "text-center" > Welcome Admin < /h1> 
      <br / > < br / >
      <hr / >
      </div> 
      <h3 className = "text-center" > Company Upload Details < /h3> 
      <div className = "container" >

      <table className = "table" >
      <thead className = "thead-light" >
      <tr >
      <th > Id < /th> <th > CompanyName < /th>
      <th > Date & Time < /th> <
      th > FileName(csv) < /th> <
      th > Size(KB) < /th> <
      th > Status < /th> <
      /tr> <
      /thead> {
        obj
      } <
      /table>
     </div> </div>
    )
  }
});
```

here is the uploads component

```
var Uploads = React.createClass({
  show() {
    this.props.saveHandle(this.props.product.id);
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td> {this.props.product.id} </td>
        <td> {this.props.product.company.companyName} </td>
        <td> {(new Date(this.props.product.date)).toString()} </td>
        <td> {this.props.product.fileName} </td>
        <td> {this.props.product.filesize} </td>
        <td> {this.props.product.status} </td>
        <td>
          <button className = "button" onClick = {this.show}> Save </button> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
});
```

Here is my code i am passing id from Uploads component to admin component when save button is clicked but it gives me an error that saveUpload is not defined.
I am confused my it is giving me that error i have a function saveUpload in Admin Component. what is wrong in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is here:

```
var obj = this.state.uploads.map(function(product) {
      return ( 
        <Uploads product = {product}
        saveHandle = {this.saveUpload}
        />
      )
    });
```

Inside the `map()`, `this` is no longer the instance of your `Admin` component, it is `window`. If you bind it like so:

```
var obj = this.state.uploads.map(function(product) {
      return ( 
        <Uploads product = {product}
        saveHandle = {this.saveUpload}
        />
      )
    }.bind(this));
```

Then `this` will point to the `Admin` instance and you should get the function you're expecting. If you have ES6 available, you could also write it like this:

```
var obj = this.state.uploads.map(product =>
        <Uploads product = {product}
        saveHandle = {this.saveUpload}
        />);
```

Using the "fat arrow" `=>` lambda expression, `this` is automatically bound to the enclosing scope inside, saving you some effort.

Comment: thank you very much i was totally confused where i had made the mistake

Comment: Glad to help — `this` is definitely one of the trickier parts of Javascript.